# If servers are "cattle", not "pets", how can I address them?

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, architecture, cloud

With the move to the cloud, and the ethos of treating of servers as "cattle", rather than as "pets", how can I address them?

Currently I might have a web service on my production server, PRODUCTION01, so I can access a web service at ... `http://PRODUCTION01/mywebservice.svc`

But if the servers are cattle and just generated as needed, how can I address the web service?

*And going even further ...*

What about when we treat the servers as "chickens", i.e. we might have labels on the cattle's ears, but chickens are just a flock ...

Comment: Just ensure you name all of them with the same name ;D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In deployments with multiple servers handling services, they usually run behind a [load balancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) which spreads requests across the multiple servers. In very large deployments the servers are typically managed with some form of automation tool, adding and removing servers from the load balancer configuration as new ones are added or old ones removed.

DNS for `PRODUCTION01` may resolve to the IP of the load balancer, the load balancer then handles distribution of requests across multiple servers.

Each server would typically have its own IP and DNS name, though typically its a private IP in a private subnet, and internal/private DNS. The servers aren't accessible directly from the public Internet.

There are other techniques that may be used instead of, or conjunction with load balancers, including [round robin dns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) and [anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) addressing.

More modern methodologies such as [containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization), [microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices), and the [serverless architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serverless_computing) are also changing the way servers and services are deployed and coordinated, often by obscuring from developers and operators, the details of how computing hardware is managed.

Comment: +1, Messaging infrastructures such as enterprise service buses could help as well, where the client just publishes a message on the bus without having to know about the consumers.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [service registry pattern](http://microservices.io/patterns/service-registry.html).